# Substring word search produces too much output

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, search, substring

I am trying to solve the coding problem below:

Given a dictionary of words
And user entered word to compare against
When comparing the given word against the dictionary
Then output all words in the dictionary that exist in the given word

E.g. StartBurst would output Star and Burst if those words were in the dictionary.

Below is my code:

```
class Program 
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
            string w = Console.ReadLine();

            string[] dictionary = new string[106];



            {
                string word = w;
                string word2 = w;
                string w1 = word;
                string w2 = word2;
                for (int n = 0; n < w.Length; n++)
                {
                    w1 = word;
                    w2 = word;
                    for (int x = 0; x < word.Length; x++)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (w1.Equals(dictionary[i]) && w1 != w2)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(w1);
                                Console.ReadLine();

                            }
                            if (w2.Equals(dictionary[i]) && w1 != w2)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(w2);
                                Console.ReadLine();
                            }

                        }
                        w1 = w1.Substring(1, w1.Length - 1);
                        w2 = word.Substring(0, word.Length - x);
                    }

                    word = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, it outputs far too much output. For example, if I enter "dontdo" the program outputs "dont do do do do do do". I believe this is due to the word = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1); statement, but I am unsure how to rectify the situation. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't this be as simple as `var matches = dictionary.Where(d => word.Contains(d));`? (This doesn't allow for case sensitivity, but then neither does your existing code..)

Comment: Why do you have 3 for loops?  The code should only have two.  One to enumerate through the words of the dictionary and one to enumerate through the letters of the word.

Comment: I think what he tries to come up with the solution that I show in this example: if the given word is jdweng it needs to search for the following: jdweng, jdwen, jdwe, jdw, eng, jd, we, ng, j, d, w, e, n and g

Answer (score 0):

I created a small code snippet for you to find all the substrings that you need in your search.

```
void Main()
{
    foreach(var w in createMatchables("real"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(w);
    }
}

// this creates all the searchable substrings from a given string
// all the strings are created from left to right
List<string> createMatchables(string str)
{
    var matchList = new List<string>();

    for (int i = str.Length; i != 0; i--)
    {
        var branchCount = str.Length / i;

        for (int j = 0; j < branchCount; j++)
        {
            matchList.Add(str.Substring(i*j, i));
        }
    }

    return matchList;
}
```